# jQuery Debugging

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug, trace, phpstorm

How prevent a debugger (Firebug or PhpStorm in this case) from step in jQuery and its plugins source code and just step over our own code?

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript debuggers have no way to determine the difference between your code and someone else's code. You're best option is to either set breakpoints before & after the blocks of code you want to skip (say a jQuery selector) so you can use the debuggers Continue feature to skip that external code.

Alternatively you can use the [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement to programmatically stop at points in the code.

Comment: I need a way to force debugger to not step into $() function. (a firebug hack, a plugin, or other ways). It should not be so hard. Selectors are scattered over entire code, seting breakpoints before & after the blocks of code is cumbersome.

Comment: You can just step over these calls instead of stepping into them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Firebug(debugger) works, The best way to debug this is to set the breakpoint at your code and try to create the scenario which hits this breakpoint first and after that you can continue to the end (skipping the jquery code).