# How to debug in jQuery the easiest way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

For example if I use this code: `$('#iddoesnotexist').remove();` I will not receive an error if this id is not in the page, **how to make to show an error?**

By default this behaviour was chosen because otherwise jQuery would regularly throw `NullReference` Exceptions, but this is what I am looking for...

Comment: I use console.log for debugging :)

Comment: You can use `console.log` or set breakpoints in devtools, or use firequery, multiple options as you can see

Comment: I think the title was a bad choice. As I understand it, you look for an option that makes jQuery throws errors on empty matches but many people are just looking at the title and recommending debugging tools...

Comment: I took a look in Firebug console log and didn't found the errors for the specific code... (I checked for show strict warnings too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own jQuery extension, I suppose. I would* write it as an assertion:

```
$.fn.mustExist = function() {
    if(!this.length) {
        throw new Error("Collection was empty.");
    }

    return this;
};
```

And during development:

```
$('#iddoesnotexist').mustExist().remove();
```

<sub>* Actually, I wouldn't use jQuery; `document.getElementById` also protects you from this kind of thing `;)`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want this behavior to be default for all DOM selection, you can create a wrapper function for the `jQuery` function.

```
var my_$ = function(selector) {
    var result = jQuery.apply(this, arguments);

    if (typeof selector === "string" && !result.length)
        throw new Error("No matches found");

    return result;               
};

my_$("#foobar"); // No matches found
```

Be sure to use your own reference instead of overwriting the `jQuery` or `$` identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[jQuery Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356116/jquery-debugging)
and 
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/debugging-tools/
and
http://www.jquery4u.com/utilities/live-jquery-debugging-firebug/
and
http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/jquery-debugging-tips/
and
http://trainofthoughts.org/blog/2007/03/16/jquery-plugin-debug/

for jQuery debugging articles. And, as mentioned in the comments, the simplest way to debug is using `console.log`.